# Has Doctor Strange become the Sorcerer Supreme?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

Has Stephen Strange officially become the Sorcerer Supreme? In *Doctor Strange*, the Ancient One was killed unexpectedly.

Strange was not appointed as the Sorcerer Supreme, but in *Thor: Ragnarok* and *Avengers: Endgame*, he wears and uses the Eye of Agamotto, but only the Sorcerer Supreme is allowed to wear the Eye of Agamotto. When Thor, Hulk, and Peter Parker came to the Sanctum for help, Strange acts like the man in power there.

In the trailer for *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, Wong asked Strange "don't cast that spell." Wong's tone was like a senior or a mentor to Strange, and his behavior is still very irresponsible in *Thor: Ragnarok*, *Avengers: Infinity War*, *Avengers: Endgame* and the *Spider-Man: No Way Home* trailer.

Is there any clue that Strange has become the Sorcerer Supreme in the MCU?

Comment: He is not acting like a senior or a mentor.   He is pleading with a friend.

Comment: I didn't take it as a question either, what Wong said.

Comment: Do we know only the Sorcerer Supreme is allowed to wear the Eye?

Comment: @MaxD Anyone who has mastered it can wear it but it's use is strictly regulated it would seem: _"You’ll wear the Eye of Agamotto once you’ve mastered its powers."_

Comment: Wong is like the senior enlisted man trying to reign in his inexperienced officer. Dumb butterbars always think they know what's what

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Strange is yet to become the Sorcerer Supreme in the MCU. At the end of *Doctor Strange* he has been made Master of the New York sanctum.

> **The Ancient One:** You defended the New York Sanctum from attack. With its Master gone, it needs another, Master Strange.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange*</sub>

It is later spelled out for us at the end of the film that the Sorcerer Supreme "job" is still vacant with interviews pending.

> **Wong:** You might have a gift for the mystic arts, but you still have much to learn. Word of the Ancient One’s death will spread through the Multiverse. Earth has no Sorcerer Supreme to defend it. We must be ready.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange*</sub>

Then in all of the media Strange appears in afterwards: *Thor: Ragnarok*, *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame* no mention is made of Strange having become the Sorcerer Supreme. For such a big event it would have at least a mention so we can assume it hasn't happened yet.

However, to answer why Wong is acting like he is in the *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, Wong *is* a mentor to Stephen. He did so in *Doctor Strange* and has carried on doing so since. However, Strange is the Master of the New York Sanctum and so is more superior to Wong (under current information anyway, things may change in NWH!). Wong can still be stern and caution Strange even if he is a lower ranked because that's what mentors and more experienced people do.

---

*What If...?* episode 4 has some extra information on this. We get the following quotes:

> **The Watcher:** The man of science became the Sorcerer Supreme.
>
> [...]
>
> **The Ancient One:** Without her death, you would never have defeated Dormammu and become the Sorcerer Supreme, and the guardian of the Eye of Agamotto.
>
> <sub>*What If...?*, Season 1 Episode 4, “What If... Doctor Strange Lost His Heart Instead of His Hands?”</sub>

This confirms that the Sorcerer Supreme is indeed a rank/leadership position. It also shows that in that universe Strange had become the Sorcerer Supreme. However, with the quotes from the main universe I don’t think it correlates to every universe and doesn’t appear to have done to the main one.

---

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, we learn that

> Wong became the Sorcerer Supreme during Strange’s absence between *Infinity War* and *Endgame*, and remains so as of the end of the movie.

Comment: Is Wong lower ranked though? Isn't it kind of hinted that he might be the Master of the Hong Kong Sanctum? I know he said he was staying to defend it, but that's because everyone there died or could have been dead. And it seemed like Wong was fairly high standing with the Ancient One, being almost like a right hand man.

Comment: @Villan Wong was/is the Librarian of Kamar-Taj. I don't think it's ever hinted at him being the Master of any sanctum, especially considering he's at New York whenever we see him. He does go to defend the New York Sanctum in IW though not the Hong Kong one.

Comment: Ah this is what I was thinking of.. Wong led a team of Masters of the Mystic Arts to defend the Sanctum against Kaecilius and his followers, but they were ultimately defeated, leading to the fall of the Hong Kong Sanctum, which was destroyed while the Dark Dimension invaded Earth. I still think that doesn't mean Strange out ranks him. What if Librarian of Kamar-Taj is higher ranked than a master of a sanctum. He is in charge of defending very serious magic.

Comment: Not to mention good advisors to people in charge will be strong-willed and independent (rather than kowtowing yes-men)... so a good advisor to the head of the Sanctum *would* say something like "whatever you do, don't use that spell". It'd still Stephen's call whether to use it, ultimately.

Comment: @Villan In addition, remember that when Dr Strange makes a joke, and Wong gives him a flat look, Dr Strange comments "people normally laugh at my jokes", and Wong responds with "and did those people work for you?"  Then, at the end of the movie, Dr Strange makes a joke, and Wong bursts out laughing…  It's a fairly clear callback.

Comment: @Chronocidal doesn't that imply that Wong doesn't work for him? People normally laugh at Strange's jokes because they work for him. Unless there's comic or mcu explanation, perhaps there is no heirarchy at all and being a master of a sanctum is just a task that you uphold and being an advisor is just a task you uphold. Maybe noone is subordinate to anyone else.

Comment: @Villan It implies that, when Dr Strange is still an apprentice, Wong doesn't work for him (obviously), but that after Dr Strange defeats Dormammu he *does*

Comment: Also... this begs the question: What is "Sorcerer Supreme"? If Thor was to die... you'd be able to say "Earth has no Thor to defend it"... not implying that "Thor" is a title but a person who can't protect it anymore. Why is SS assumed to be a title of rank/leadership? Could it not just be another title like "The Ancient One"?

Comment: @WernerCD the Sorcerer Supreme per my understanding is the “leader” of the Masters. So it is a rank/leadership position. Also the Ancient One is a moniker/nickname and not a title.

Comment: @LethalCarrot is it actually stated somewhere that it's rank/leadership and not just another moniker/nickname? Might be another question if of itself but "The earth no longer has Iron Man as its defender" doesn't mean Iron Man is a rank like the Dali Lama. Only things I found worth note are more comic book related and seem to put it as more of a skill level than a "rank" - as there are many SS in THAT universe it seems https://www.cbr.com/doctor-strange-the-10-best-sorcerer-supremes-ranked/

Comment: @WernerCD To me even if nothing explicit is stated outright the implications given are that it's a rank/leadership position. Combine that with the information from the comics and we can be pretty sure.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The timeline/events doesn't really differ that much from that episode and the 'main' one, they are 'the same', except for the reason as to why he seeks the mystic arts, until later after Dormamu (we don't know for sure when). So I would argue that we can consider him a Sorcerer supreme in the 'main' one as well, since it seems that defeating Dormamu made him the Sorcerer supreme. Or my understanding of the sentence the ancient one said isn't right ?

Comment: @PhilippeB. I think your understanding is right. However, the diverge happens when he decides to bring Christine with him. The lines stay similar but different. As such I don’t think we can say Strange is the Sorcerer Supreme in the main timeline. Especially with what Wong says at the end of _Doctor Strange_.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ohh you're right I thought Wong quote was before Dormamu and not after (just rewatched the end of DS), which changes the meaning of the sentence of the ancient one in What If... as "her death" is what leads him to defeat Dormamu AND become the Sorcerer Supreme, defeating Dormamu isn't what is making him the Sorcerer Supreme. I get it now and your answer still stands. Thank you.

Comment: Additional confirmation from She-Hulk episode 3: Wong repeatedly refers to himself as Sorcerer Supreme.

Answer (score 3):

## At the moment, it's not entirely clear.

[The Marvel Fandom page](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange) for the MCU version of Dr. Strange states that he is currently the Sorcerer Supreme:

> **Doctor Stephen Vincent Strange M.D., Ph.D is the Sorcerer Supreme and a Master of the Mystic Arts.** Originally a brilliant, although arrogant, neurosurgeon, Strange got into a car accident which resulted with his hands becoming crippled. When all Western medicine failed him, Strange embarked on a journey that led him into Kamar-Taj where Strange had made the discovery of magic and alternate dimensions, being trained by the Ancient One. Though focused on healing his hands and returning into his career, Strange learned more of the mystic arts and helped the Masters prevent Kaecilius from merging the Earth with the Dark Dimension, but not before witnessing the Ancient One's death. Following the demise of their mentor, Strange became the protector of the New York Sanctum in New York as well as the Earth's protector from any new inter-dimensional threats.

That in itself doesn't prove anything, as Marvel Fandom is not an official source. However, the page does offer a citation from an official source, that being [Dr. Strange's bio on Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/doctor-strange-stephen-strange/on-screen/profile), which states the following:

> Formerly a renowned surgeon, **Doctor Stephen Strange now serves as the Sorcerer Supreme**—Earth’s foremost protector against magical and mystical threats.

This statement appears above the entries for both the MCU and comics versions of Strange.

[image] [image]

Given that this page combines entries for both versions though, I'm not convinced that the Sorcerer Supreme statement applies specifically to the MCU version.

If you look further down the entry for the comics version, it again states that he's *"Earth's Sorcerer Supreme"*, whereas the entry for the MCU version just says that he's *"Earth's newest Master of the Mystic Arts"*.

And the [In Comics Full Report](https://www.marvel.com/characters/doctor-strange-stephen-strange/in-comics) section documents the specific circumstances in which the comics version of Strange became Sorcerer Supreme, whereas the [On Screen Full Report](https://www.marvel.com/characters/doctor-strange-stephen-strange/on-screen) section says nothing about the MCU version receiving that title.

Also, as noted in [TheLethalCarrot's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/253048/122024), Wong stated at the end of *Doctor Strange* (2016) that Earth had no Sorcerer Supreme at that time.

> Wong: You might have a gift for the mystic arts, but you still have much to learn. Word of the Ancient One’s death will spread through the Multiverse. **Earth has no Sorcerer Supreme to defend it.** We must be ready.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange* (2016)</sub>

It's possible that MCU Strange became Sorcerer Supreme some time *after* this, but it seems odd that Marvel would choose to have such an important moment for the character happen entirely off-screen, and neglect to even mention it in passing in any of the movies.

It's also worth bearing in mind that the comics version of Dr. Strange didn't become the Sorcerer Supreme until a full decade after his first appearance. He debuted in *[Strange Tales Vol. 1 #110](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_110)* in July 1963, but didn't inherit the title of Sorcerer Supreme from the Ancient One until *[Marvel Premiere #10](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Premiere_Vol_1_10)* in September 1973.

[image]

<sub>*Marvel Premiere #10*</sub>

The latter issue also featured the first confrontation between Dr. Strange and [Shuma-Gorath](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Shuma-Gorath_(Multiverse)). It's rumoured that Shuma-Gorath will appear in the upcoming *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), and if so, that would seem like the perfect time to have Dr. Strange become the Sorcerer Supreme within the MCU.

We'll obviously have to wait and see if that's what will actually happen though.

Comment: Cal’s going to be in the movies too? Excellent! (I call Shuma-Gorath Cal for short, I’m trying to make it a thing. It’s short for calamari.)

Comment: It's still [just a rumour](https://www.theilluminerdi.com/2021/05/18/shuma-gorath-america-chavez/) at this point, but we've now seen a tentacled creature bearing a strong resemblance to Cal in two episodes of _What If...?_, which could be foreshadowing for a future appearance in the movies.

Comment: screw Kang, Cal () is where it’s at for the next 6–7 years.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Stephen Strange is the Sorcerer Supreme on the MCU.

This exchange from Hulk and The Ancient One on Endgame proves it.

> Ancient One: It's the duty of the Sorcerer Supreme to protect the Time Stone."

> Hulk: Then why the hell did Strange give it away?"

> Ancient One: What did you say?

> Hulk: Strange. He gave it away. He gave it to Thanos.

Yo me that implicitly recognises Strange as the Sorcerer Supreme in two fronts. First as protector of the Time Stone quite explicitly, second by the reaction (or lack of thereof) of the Ancient One.

Comment: It proves that Hulk thinks Strange is the Sorcerer Supreme, but I don’t think any of Banner’s eight doctorates are in the Mystic Arts. The Ancient One was probably focusing a bit more on why Stevie boy gave the fricking Time Stone away, rather the wizard rankings of the future.

Comment: If you want to take that position fine. But Doctor Strange IS the protector of the Time Stone as stated by himself in Infinity War

Answer (score 1):

### Wong is the Sorcerer Supreme "by a technicality".

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021),

> Peter Parker seeks out the help of Doctor Strange to make people forget he is Spider-Man.

Parker refers to Strange as the "Sorcerer Supreme" but Strange refutes this, saying that Wong became the Sorcerer Supreme "by a technicality"; when Strange dusted, the Earth had to have a Sorcerer Supreme, and so Strange lost the title and has not regained it as of the events of *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, if he ever had it to begin with.

Comment: This merely repeats information in the accepted answer

Comment: Whoops, I see that now...

Answer (score 0):

We find out in What If...? Episode Four that Doctor Strange does indeed become the Sorcerer Supreme, but that is an alternate version of him, his Earth 616 version hasn't been confirmed by Marvel to be the Sorcerer Supreme.

Comment: _What If..?_ S01E04 only confirmed that Strange was the Sorcerer Supreme in that alternate timeline. It's possible that he's also currently the Sorcerer Supreme in the timeline the movies are set in, but that is unconfirmed. The upcoming sequel may shed more light on that, so I'd wait for that before forming firm conclusions one way or the other.

Comment: If you search up if Doctor Strange is the Sorcerer Supreme, the first result is that the Marvel Cinematic Universe has confirmed that he is, meaning he is in the movies.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://screenrant.com/what-if-episode-4-doctor-strange-sorcerer-supreme/) Screen Rant article? If so, the clickbait headline says Strange was confirmed to be the Sorcerer Supreme, but the body of the article acknowledges that this was only confirmed in the alternate timeline, and that it is still unconfirmed within the main timeline.

Comment: No, that is what the MCU confirmed for the alternate timeline, but in Marvel Fandom it says that he is the Sorcerer Supreme in Earth-616, which is the Doctor Strange from the movie. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Here is what it says on the article: Dr. Stephen Strange, M.D., a.k.a. Doctor Strange, was the Sorcerer Supreme for Earth-616. Strange was once a brilliant but arrogant neurosurgeon, until a car accident crippled his hands. When modern medicine failed him, he embarked on a journey to Kamar-Taj in Tibet, where he was trained by the Ancient One. He healed his hands and learned more about Magic, eventually becoming a Master of the Mystic Arts. He settled in the Sanctum Sanctorum in Greenwich Village, New York City, becoming the Earth's protector from any mystical threats.

Comment: [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616) is the main universe in the comics, so the article you're quoting is talking about the comics version of Strange, not the movie version.

Comment: Yes, but Earth-616 is also in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. I am so sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Loki'd you're confusing something here. The main plot of the MCU is indeed based on events that occured on Earth-616 but this earth isn't the MCU earth since there is a lot of differences. I cannot find any reference to the MCU in the Earth-616 wiki. But if you look for MCU on the Marvel Fandom you will find [this](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Earth) which is the earth from the MCU also know as [Earth-199999](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-199999_(disambiguation)). Which confirms that as of now, we have nothing that proves DS is the Sorcerer Supreme.

Comment: and still @Loki'd- Marvel Fandom isn't a resource of record, it's a fan sourced wiki. I could go edit it right now to say that Earth-616 is actually a universe consisting of a piece of moldy cheese in a dungeon on Magrathea. It's not in any way official

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback, I will improve on my answer.